# In Scala, is there a way to have two overloaded methods that only differ in whether an implicit is available?

Tags: scala, overloading

I'm writing a Scala application that accesses a database. Most of the time, there will be a connection available, but sometimes there won't be. What I'd like to do is something like the following:

```
object User {
  def authenticate(username: String, password: String)
      (implicit conn: Connection): Option[User] = {
    // use conn to grab user from db and check that password matches
    // return Some(user) if so, None if not
  }
  def authenticate(username: String, password: String): Option[User] = {
    implicit val conn = DB.getConnection()
    authenticate(username, password)
  }
}
```

What I hoped would happen is that, if there's an implicit value of type `Connection` available, the compiler would use the first method. If not, it would use the second. Unfortunately, I've discovered that the compiler isn't quite that smart or, if it is, I'm not telling it what to do in the right way.

So, my basic question is, is there a way to write a method that expects an implicit argument and then provide an overloaded version of the same method that creates an acceptable value of the implicit parameter's type if there isn't one available.

You might say, "Why would you want to do such a thing? If you can create an acceptable value of the appropriate type, why not just always do it?" And that's mostly true, except that if I have an open database connection, I'd prefer to go ahead and use it rather than creating a new one. However, if I don't have an open database connection, I know where to get one.

I mean, the simple answer is to just give the two methods different names, but I shouldn't have to, gosh-darn-it. But maybe I do...

Thanks!
Todd

Comment: What about wrapping the the connection in some class responsible for calling `getConnection` and storing? Then you would need only one method taking this new class as implicit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need overloaded methods. Just give your implicit parameter a default value, i.e.

```
object User {
  def authenticate(username:String, password:String)(implicit conn:Connection = null): Option[User] = {
    val real_conn = Option(conn).getOrElse(DB.getConnection())
    // do the rest with the real_conn
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not implicit conn:Option[Connection] ?

Comment: conn will be null if you don't give an implicit value in scope, and it will take that value otherwise. And of course you can use Option[Connection] but that require you to modify your context codes, that may be a lot of changes.

Comment: @pedrofurla: I wondered about this too the first time I saw it, but [it's legit](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf): "If the parameter has a default argument and no implicit argument can be found the default argument is used."

Comment: Oh, oh, sorry, i didn't see the default arg. My bad. Removing the comment.

Comment: Now why didn't that occur to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner solution which I can think of is using nested methods and as someone suggested, default values for implicits.

```
class Testclass {

  def myMethod(a:Int)(implicit b:Option[Int]=None):Int = {

    def myMethodInternal(a:Int, b:Int):Int = {
      // do something
      a+b
    }
    val toUse = b.getOrElse(30)
    myMethodInternal(a,toUse)
  }
}
```

Inside your method you define an myMethodInternal, which takes no implicits but only explicits parameters. This method will be visible only inside myMethod, and you will prepare your second parameter like the following:

```
  val toUse = b.getOrElse(30)
```

And finally call your method with  explicits parameters:

```
  myMethodInternal(a,toUse)
```